# transform scale after rotate

Tags: css

I have a problem. I am rotating an div 45 degrees. I then want to scale it on the new y axis http://jsfiddle.net/P37g5/2/ - not the y axis that is now at 45 degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your object like this:

CSS

```
span {
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: rgba(240,240,240,1);
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div{
    -moz-transform:scale(1, 5); 
    -webkit-transform:scale(1, 5);
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

[(View on jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/P37g5/5/)

Answer (score 17):

I´m not sure I understand the question correctly, but if you change the order of the transformations, your `div` is scaled along the regular y-axis:

```
div {
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: rgba(240,240,240,1);
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1.5) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1.5) rotate(45deg);
}
```

**Edit:** [From w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-values): If a list of transforms is provided, then the net effect is as if each transform had been specified separately in the order provided.

Comment: It appears the transforms are applied in reverse order (right to left).