# CSS3: How to rotate and scale an img at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I'm very confused. Why can't I use scale and rotate at the same time? I've tried this, but it does not work:

```
.rotate-img{
    -webkit-transform:scale(2,2);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-top:10%;
}
```

I tried jQuery, but does not work neither:

```
<style>
.zoom{
        -webkit-transform:scale(2,2);
        margin-left:20%;
        margin-top:10%;
    }
</style>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img").dblclick(function(){

            $(this).addClass("zoom");

            $(this).contextmenu(function(){
                $(this).css("-webkit-transform","rotate(90deg)");
                return false;
            })
        });
    })

    </script>
```

How could I scale an img and when I clic the right click then rotate 90 deg.

Comment: What happens when you try the code as-is, and what browser did you try it in?

Comment: What it happend is that the img rotate 90deg but the scale property get lower, i mean, the img goes back to its original scale. And im using Google Chrome. @Adrian

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yKF8d/ - works here

Comment: Beware of the `,` when writing `2,2`, you probably want `2.2`

Comment: `2,2` means scale horizontally by 2x and vertically by 2x. You can shorten it to just `2` since both dimensions are the same. Lots of code examples on the web use the `x,y` format even if the numbers are the same.

Answer (score 87):

You can rotate an image with CSS using the `transform` property with a `rotate(**deg)` value

```css
.rotate-img {
    -webkit-transform : rotate(90deg) scale(0.2); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform     : rotate(90deg) scale(0.2); /* IE 9 */
    transform         : rotate(90deg) scale(0.2); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    left : -200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img class="rotate-img" src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" />
```

When applying `transform` on multiple lines, it's like any other CSS property, and it gets overwritten so only the last line is used, just like with something like :

```
.myclass {
    top: 100px;
    top: 400px;
}
```

only the last one would apply, so you'll need to put all the transformations in one `transform`.

Comment: Note that the ordering matters - you probably want to `rotate` and then `scale` (as written above) to maintain the perspective of your element; reversing the order will deform the element. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5395185/957950.

Answer (score 16):

Well, building on top of adeneo's answer, one that includes all browers capable of [CSS transform](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

```
.rotate-img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2.2); /* Chrome 4+, Op 15+, Saf 3.1, iOS Saf 3.2+ */
       -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2.2); /* Fx 3.5-15 */
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2.2); /* IE 9 */
         -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2.2); /* Op 10.5-12 */
            transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2.2); /* Fx 16+, IE 10+ */
    margin: 10% 0 0 20%;
}
```

See extended [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/5eFWQ/).

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to write code separately to use both rotate and scale
u can use it look like this :

transform: scale(1.3) rotate(7deg);

Answer (score 2):

You can scale & rotate at the same time, but you HAVE to do it on the same line, otherwise you overwrite the prievius value with the new value.

```js
let htmlElement = document.getElementById("rotate-img");
let scaleX = -0.3;
let scaleY =  0.2;
let angle  =  45 ;

// NOTICE!! THE BACK-TICKS, not regular quotes. Will decode variables inside before printing.

// Code for Safari
htmlElement.style.WebkitTransform = `scale( ${scaleX}, ${scaleY} ) rotate( ${angle}deg )`; 

// Code for IE9
htmlElement.style.msTransform = `scale( ${scaleX}, ${scaleY} ) rotate( ${angle}deg )`; 

// Standard syntax
htmlElement.style.transform = `scale( ${scaleX}, ${scaleY} ) rotate( ${angle}deg )`;
```

```html
<img id="rotate-img" src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" />
```

Also notice that any already existing style on that element will be overwritten, unless you save that style into a (string-)variable first & add (append or concatenate) the new styles to that saved variable & then add the whole variable back onto the html-element.